# AngularJS service rootscope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a service defined in AngularJS with `app.factory("serviceName", function($rootScope) { .. })`
If I do `$rootScope.$apply()`, would that re-evaluate ALL the controller's scopes in the app or just the scopes of the controllers which use this service?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[$digest()](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24digest) only "flushes" the current scope and all of its child scopes.

[$apply(exp)](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24rootScope.Scope#%24apply) evaluates the exp and then calls $digest() on the root scope.  So calling $apply() (on any scope) affects all scopes.

If you call $digest() and your action changes some parent scope, the change will not be observed. So normally you want to call $apply().  (If you're tempted to try and be more efficient by calling $digest(), it can bite you later!)

Comment: digest is really what I needed. I have always used $apply with the idea that it affects only the current scope.

Answer (score 1):

There's only one root scope per application. Calling `$rootScope.$apply()` will trigger a digest cycle that will dirty check **the entire scope tree**.

To avoid this, call `$apply` from the controller's scope or its parent scope if you want to dirty-check multiple sibling scopes.

Comment: I think you meant to say $digest in the 2nd paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

The code below will log `MyCtrl` and `MyCtrl2` to the console every two seconds, suggesting that **any $apply to any $scope**, will digest **all scopes**. The question is against which scope the applied function will run. If it dirty check only the applied scope, the `MyCtrl` shouldn't be logged. Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/CaioToOn/hDZVx/).

```js
var mod = angular.module('MyApp', []);

mod.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.value = function() {
        console.log('MyCtrl');
        return 'value';
    };

    setInterval(function() {
        $scope.$apply()
    }, 2000);
});

mod.controller('MyCtrl2', function($scope) {
    $scope.value2 = function() {
        console.log('MyCtrl2');
        return 'value 2';
    };
});​
```

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">{{value()}}</div>
  <div ng-controller="MyCtrl2">{{value2()}}</div>
</div>​
```