# Changes to service bound to controller scope not visible

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a service to hold data (in an associative array) that's important to multiple controllers. The data this service holds is updated asynchronously. In my controller I make a variable on the scope myService and assign to it the service. Then, in my view, I reference the data as myService.theInterestingData . In case this is important, in the view, I am referencing the interestingData assoc array in an ng-repeat.

For some reason, when the data is updated (I get console logs), the visible page does not change, but if I perform some UI action (for example open the snap-drawer http://jtrussell.github.io/angular-snap.js/), then the data is updated, but further changes will also require some UI action before they're visible.

I must be doing something wrong. Any suggestion as to how I can fix this? I thought perhaps I need $apply to be called, but the data is on the service which has no reference to the controller on whose scope I'd need to $apply

See these 2 versions of a fiddle. Both show the same logging, but one (not surprisingly the one that uses $interval http://jsfiddle.net/a6Nhs/5/ ) updates the "screen" (what am I talking about here? the DOM?) and the other (window.setInterval http://jsfiddle.net/a6Nhs/4/ ) does not. In my actual app it is not an interval that causes the asynchronous update, but receiving information over a websocket, and so the solution for me is not so easy as changing to $interval.

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  Hello, {{name}}!
    {{numsService}}
    <li ng-repeat="(key,val) in numsService.nums">
        {{key}} | {{val}}
    </li>
</div>
```

and the js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

//myApp.directive('myDirective', function() {});
myApp.service('myService', function() {
    this.nums={};
    this.total = 0;
});

myApp.service('differentService', function(myService, $interval){
    $interval(function(){ //using $interval works, using window.setInterval does not
        console.log('diffService');
        myService.nums[myService.total+'idx']=myService.total++;
        console.log(myService.nums);
    }, 1000);
});

function MyCtrl($scope, myService, differentService) {
    $scope.name = 'Superhero';
    $scope.numsService = myService;
}
```

Comment: I recommend you do a plunker http://plnkr.co/ to show your example.

Comment: @PeterFromCologne added fiddle and code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try $apply on $rootScope:

```
myApp.service('differentService', function(myService, $rootScope){
     window.setInterval(function(){
        $rootScope.$apply(function(){
            console.log('diffService');
            myService.nums[myService.total+'idx']=myService.total++;
            console.log(myService.nums);
        });
    }, 1000);
  });
```

Normally, when you call $apply(exp) on the scope, it actually evaluates the exp and then calls $digest() on the **root scope**. Take a look at this [AngularJS service rootscope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906636/angularjs-service-rootscope)

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rrHP4/1/)

Answer (score 1):

As a modification to Khanh TO's answer, I'd say avoid `$rootScope.$apply()`, use `$timeout` which attempts to apply the changes to data during the next digest and thus avoids errors when you may end up with concurrent `$apply's` and does away with the lag. I'd do:

```
myApp.service('differentService', function (myService, $rootScope) {
    $timeout(function(){
        myService.nums[myService.total+'idx']=myService.total++;
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Ashesh, but since this is happening in a service, I won't end up with concurrent `$apply`s, also see the part of my comment where I explain that the timer is merely to illustrate asynchrony, not my actual use case.